# New Year's what?

Tags: american-english, north-american-english

I have often noticed that Americans say "New Years" - and wondered why it was plural.

But just reading Obama's biography I've noticed for the first time it is spelled with an apostrophe.

*School started two weeks before Inauguration Day, so after **New Year's** we flew back to Chicago...*

In Britain we would just say "after New Year", or we might say "after New Year's Day". But I am puzzled as to how America got to "New Year's". It could mean a whole lot of things - "New Year's Eve", "New Year's Day", New Year's holiday" (which we would call "the New Year public/bank-holiday*"), "New Year's picnic" etc.

Does anyone have any thoughts about this?

*If New Year's Day falls at the weekend, the Monday following is a public holiday - (often still called a "bank holiday" in Britain).

Comment: [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/happy-new-year-2/#:~:text=Here's%20what%20to%20say%20at,we%20don't%20judge) seems to have discussed the topic.

Comment: I think it's short for "New Year's celebration" but that's just a guess. Maybe an American can explain it but I wouldn't put money on it. After all a lot of them think that there is something called a 'tooth comb' that you use to go through things in fine detail. Everyone else thinks it's a "fine-tooth comb" which makes perfect sense.

Comment: Brits don't generally go for this particular possessive, but it's similar to the way we "apostrophise" ***Tesco's*** and ***Sainsbury's*** (which the companies themselves almost never do, and I'm not sure why the general public rarely do this with some other  nationwide chains, such as ***Lidl, Aldi, Asda***).

Comment: In the UK, I'd say 'after the New Year' is more idiomatic than the anarthrous version.

Comment: AFF Then there's **Lloyds**, not to be confused with **Lloyd's**.  And **Waterstones** née **Waterstone's**. And in the States, **The Long Island Writers' Guild** and  **Redbud Writers Guild**. And everywhere,  a  **nine day wonder**. The jury is still out on whether to include an s, with or without apostrophe.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I think the shop example - *Tesco's* etc - has its origins in people and their houses. E.g. The person who lives at the end of the road is named *Charlie*. I ask someone "Please would you drop this in to *Charlie's* on your way past". I suppose this is short for *Charlie's house*, *Charlie's door* or *Charlie's letter-box* - it doesn't matter which. So *Tesco's* one might argue is *Tesco's shop*. But I'm puzzled how *New Year's* became short for *New Year's Day* (See GEdgar below). I can't think of any other examples like it.  Does *Washington's birthday* become *Washington's*?

Comment: @WS2: There's also *Let's meet at John's* (house, place), and *I'll have a ploughman's* (lunch). And (more popular in the US than the UK, I suspect) *I'll have a Danish* (pastry), which is essentially the same kind of ***non-explicitly stated noun** [implied by a possessive form closely associated with that noun].*

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be an AmE usage and it may refer to either New Years’s Day or Eve, according to context.

***[New Year's](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/new-year)*** (uncountable noun)

> New Year's is another name for New Year's Day or , New Year's Eve. [US]

(Collins Dictionary)

but  according to [Grammarly.com](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/happy-new-year-2/):

> “New Year’s” usually means “New Year’s Eve,” and people usually specify “New Year’s Day” when they’re talking about January 1.

while according to [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/New%20Year)

New year:

> usually New Year's : New Year’s  day

[thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/new-years/) about the usage of “New Year’s” points out that:

> you should also use the ‘s even when New Year’s stands alone as long as you’re talking about the holiday. For example: “Let’s plan to get together for New Year’s.”

> Here, the ‘s implies the eve or day. You should, however, probably get a bit more specific with your friends so they don’t show up on New Year’s Eve when you’re in your pajamas and were actually inviting them to brunch on New Year’s Day. Just saying.

Comment: But if it is a noun, which indeed it is - a proper noun like *Easter* or *Christmas* - then why would it require an apostrophe s?  And I'm not clear about your reference "Oxford Languages". The Oxford English Dictionary records it as a noun, and makes no mention about any apostrophe - though since the OED is a dictionary of the full corpus of the English Language as spoken around the world - perhaps it should include it as an American curiosity. The most recent example the OED gives is *1999   J. M. Coetzee Disgrace i. 5   At New Year he gave her an enamelled bracelet.*

Comment: @WS2 ... In the *OED* see the separate entry "New Year's, *n.*"  This says "Chiefly *North American*" and claims it is shortened from "New Year's Day" with no mention of "Eve".

Comment: @GEdgar Well spotted! One would have thought the OED would have cross-referenced the entries.